# How can I add two different tensorflow models from two different applications?

Tags: tensorflow, ocr

I use two models from two diffrent applications. First one is [EAST Scene Text Detector](https://github.com/argman/EAST) and second is [Calamari Ocr](https://github.com/Calamari-OCR/calamari). *Both of them use Tensorflow.* Code is as followed:

```
east_detector = EASTDetector(model_path='east_models/EAST_IC15+13_model.h5')
calamari = ocr.Predictor(checkpoint='calamari_models/model_00623553.ckpt')
```

There is not a parameter, method etc to set Tensorflow session for both applications. Is there a way to allow two models to run in same tf session?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked how to do it in TensorFlow 2 but I have implemented it in TF-1 quite a year back.

you can check this [python Notebook](https://github.com/CS-savvy/keras-preprocessing-inject/blob/master/merge_two_model.ipynb)

here I have merged two Xception models in one by averaging their output of the softmax layer(kind off ensembling technique.)

For Keras model(h5), you need to convert that model from h5 to ckpt formate to use the above code using [tf.Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/Saver).